# Android Studio doesn't recognize InstanceID class

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I want to implement GCM Client on Android. 
Following the guide here
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client
I have downloaded the configuration file and copied the **google-services.json** file into the **app/** directory of the project.

I have also added the dependencies in the project's build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

and plugin in the app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have also included the **Google Play Services SDK**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

I have also updated the AndroidManifest.xml file as shown here
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

To get the Registration Token, when I use the following code

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

Android Studio does not recognize the class. I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'InstaceID'". Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: if issue is resolved then please post here, i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to use the **latest version of the Google Play Services, Android Support Repository and Google Repository** for this to work, and then include the latest version of the Google Play Services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

Update your Play services SDK to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Then clean your Project.

Worked for me. Hope it works for you too!

Comment: I actually have the latest version of Google Play Services SDK (re. 25 on 14th July 2015). The problem was that I didn't have the latest versions of Android Support Repository and Google Repository. Thank You!

Comment: I meet the same problem, but I have the latest Google Play Service SDK and the latest versions of Android Support Repository and Google Repository, but the AS still can not resolve the classes of GCM. PS: it occurs after I update my AS to 1.3  in the stable channel

Answer (score 6):

you are missing the **gcm**

add on your gradle:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks an official firebase documentation and imports the latest version om.google.firebase:firebase-messaging

eg: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'`